# How to create Scientific calculator in Android like Real Calc?

Tags: java, android, calculator

i am newbie for Android Development. i don't have any idea for creating Scientific Calculator.but i want create to that. so please some one tell me solution...

Comment: You need to work on the solution first and then come here for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is an open source Scientific Calculator example available. Check it out.

[scientific-calculator](http://code.google.com/p/scientific-calculator-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/google/calculator)

And one more in GitHub, [android--Scientific-Graphing-Calculator](https://github.com/sampullman/android--Scientific-Graphing-Calculator)